# Minor changes in code or preprocess in Java for different builds?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, preprocessor

I am working on my Android game called Flat Out Hockey using eclipse as an IDE, Java and native C++.
My issue is with the Java part of the code.
Since I need to build my game for both FireTV, Google Play and OUYA I have different ways to deal with gamepad input on each platform.
One issue is that FireTV uses a different "Project Build Target" than Google Play and OUYA, something specifically made for FireTV by Amazon.

This means I need to use imports and classes that are available under one build target but not on the other and keep switching between them when I build for each platforms.

The issue is that as far as I know there is no preprocessor in Java?
So I just can't do #ifdef like in C++.
This makes the amount of code I need to comment/uncomment or change the values more than it should be.

One "trick" I did was to create a kind of a mimic class for the Amazon gamepad class so I would just change the imports and have a class with the same name but different functionality.

But there are other issues, like the Immersive attribute which is only available on Android OS 5.
And other stuff.

So maybe I am missing some feature in Java, but I would really like to just have to set a single value in a single place to switch between different builds.

Is there anything like that in Java/eclipse?

Comment: in Android Studio, you can define flavors for your build, in which you can place specific code. Typically this is used for dev/release builds, but it can be used for all kinds of things, including that.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to split your project into several components: a "core" module that defines the main implementation in terms of common interfaces (which it defines), and then a module per target that declares implementations of those interfaces.

So for instance, your core module may define a GamePad interface, and then your FireAdapter module would depend on both the core and Fire's API to create a FireGamePad (which implements GamePad).

Each module then becomes it own build, with its own deliverable.

Comment: How would I make a different AndroidManifest for each one of those builds in eclipse?
Or in other words how would I change the version and build number in one place for all 3 builds?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with AndroidManifest or Eclipse, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use java Comment Preprocessor https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor , I made some experiments with usage for Android https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor/wiki/AndroidGradlePreprocessing but not very deeply, the preprocessor was developed in 2002 specially for small changes in J2ME projects to avoid huge number of the classes with the same functionality but with small differences for vendor specific parts